# How can I convert a list of strings into sympy variables?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a list of strings, e.g., `var = ['x', 'y', 'z']`. I want to use these strings as sympy 'symbols'. I am trying to do this:

```
for i in var:
    i = symbols('i')
```

it's not working of course. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason what you did did not work is because you tried to assign a symbol to a string which can't be changed (e.g. 'a' = 1 will fail for the same reason).

If you are working interactively and want variables with the same name as the symbols you can write

```
>>> var(','.join(variables)) # variables = ['x', 'y', 'z']
(x, y, z)
```

On a related note, sometimes you sympify an expression and would like to also have access to the variables, interactively. You can use `var` for this, too:

```
>>> eq = S('x + y')
>>> var(','.join([s.name for s in eq.atoms(Symbol)]))
(x, y)
>>> eq.diff(x)
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Several issues:

1. The input string is never mutated by a call to `sympy.symbols`.
2. You need to call `symbols` with every element of `var` as an argument, you hardcoded a call with the string argument `'i'`.
3. The assignment to `i` inside the loop body is pointless because in the next iteration the name `i` will be reassigned to the next element from `var` (which you don't even use).

So in summary, you need to call `symbols` with every element of `var` and store the return values somewhere.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> var_as_strings = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> var_as_symbol_objects = [sympy.symbols(v) for v  in var_as_strings]
>>> var_as_symbol_objects
[x, y, z]
>>> type(var_as_symbol_objects[0])
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

(I used overly verbose variable names to be make the example self-documenting.)

Comment: If I use "from sympy import *" and write "symbols(v)" rather than    "sympy.symbols(v)", it should also work..right? @timgeb

Comment: @PushanSharma yes