# Convert list of strings SymPy to symbols and use in solveset

Tags: python, sympy

The post "[How can I convert a list of strings into sympy variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972499/how-can-i-convert-a-list-of-strings-into-sympy-variables)" discusses how to generate SymPy symbols from a list of strings. My question is what steps are needed to use these symbols x, y and z in SymPy calculations?

I tried something along the lines

```
from sympy import symbols, solveset

var_as_strings = ['x', 'y', 'z']
var_as_symbol_objects = [sympy.symbols(v) for v  in var_as_strings]
var_as_symbol_objects

for x1, x2 in zip(var_as_symbol_objects, var_as_strings):
    x1 = symbols(x2)

soln = solveset(x-y-z, x)
```

but I get the error "NameError: name 'x' is not defined". Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Python variables in the current namespace from a list of strings (or a string of space or comma separated names) with `var`:

```
>>> names = 'x y z'  # or 'x, y, z'
>>> var(names)
(x, y, z)
>>> var(list('xyz'))
[x, y, z]
>>> var(set('xyz'))
{x, y, z}
```

In all cases, after issuing the `var` command you will be able to use variables that have been assigned SymPy symbols with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered by the first listed gotcha in [the documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#symbols).

You need to store your symbols into the required variables manually (`x = symbols('x')`), or import them from `sympy.abc` (`from sympy.abc import x`).

The name error is happening because you haven't defined what `x`, `y` or `z` are in your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the thing is that I have a lot of items in my list that I wish to define as symbols just using the list of strings (doing it manually isn't an option)... Is there any way of writing a loop that defines all strings in a list as symbols?

Comment: You've already done that in your third line of (non-empty) code, but that won't add them to your global namespace - you've just stored the symbols into a list. You might need to insert them into the global namespace manually, but I'd make the argument that that is a very risky and convoluted thing to do. You're honestly much better off just importing `from sympy.abc import *` if you need an absolute ton of symbols.

Answer (score 0):

> that I have a lot of items in my list that I wish to define as symbols

Just FYI, a snippet which can automatically define the symbols in an *enhanced* fashion

```
nmax = 7
names = ["phi" + str(i) for i in range(nmax)]
sympy_vars = [symbols("\\" + name.replace("phi", "phi_")) for name in names]
globals().update(dict(zip(names, sympy_vars)))
phi0
```

This yields a nice LaTeX type output in, e.g., jupyter notebooks.